# Clojure Recursive Log Table

Tags: recursion, clojure, logarithm

```
(ns logtable) 


(defn displayLogTable[start stop step]
    (if (> start stop) nil
        (if < star stop) log10 start)
        (displayLogTable ( + start step) stop step)
        )
))





(defn -main []
    (println "\n Enter your start, stop and step: ")
        (let 
            [ start stop step (Integer/parseInt (read-line))]
            (print (displayLogTable start stop step)
        )

    )
```

I'm getting a "Too many arguments to if" error 
I'm trying to implement a recursive function to print out my log table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors in this part of the code:

```clj
(defn displayLogTable[start stop step]
    (if (> start stop) nil
        (if < star stop) log10 start)
        (displayLogTable ( + start step) stop step)
        )
))
```

Formatting to make it obvious:

```clj
(defn displayLogTable[start stop step]
  (if (> start stop)
    nil ; 1
    (if <  ;2
      star 
      stop) 
    log10 ; 3
    start) ; 4
  (displayLogTable (+ start step) stop step))
)) ; to much closing parens
```

The `if` has too many forms (1-4), where only three are allowed `(if predicate then else)`.  The if at `2` is correctly formed, but for sure not what you want (if `<` is true (always) then `star` (typo, most likely `start`) else `stop`).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If we correct your code along the lines that [@cfrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60464205/1562315) implies, we get something like ...

```
(defn displayLogTable [start stop step]
    (if (> start stop)
      nil
      (if (< start stop)
        (Math/log10 start)
        (displayLogTable (+ start step) stop step))))
```

This doesn't make much sense. We can simplify it to ...

```
(defn displayLogTable [start stop step]
  (loop [start start]
    (cond 
      (> start stop) nil
      (< start stop) (Math/log10 start)
      :else (recur ( + start step)))))
```

Equally futile. It looks as though you want the sequence of logarithms of the range of numbers defined by `start`, `stop`, and `step`. One way to do this in Clojure is ...

```
(defn displayLogTable [start stop step]
  (map
    (fn [x] (Math/log10 x))
    (range start stop step)))
```

For example, ...

```
=> (displayLogTable 1 10 1)
(0.0 0.3010299956639812 0.47712125471966244 0.6020599913279624 0.6989700043360189 
 0.7781512503836436 0.8450980400142568 0.9030899869919435 0.9542425094393249)
```

Notice that `range` is inclusive of the start point (`0`) but exclusive of the end point (`10`).

Clojure's means of dealing with [sequences](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences) (`map` and `range` occur here) are often the key to solving problems like this.